# Printing 9x9 array instead of 10x10 array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, draw, rectangles

I'm new to C++ and am in the process of learning, please help.

I've a 2d array of [10][10] as stated below. I can only print out [1][0] array onwards, why is this so?

```
const int row = 10;
const int column = 10;

int test2[row][column] = {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }
};
```

Then from here, I did a double for loop to draw something out.

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            {
                if (test2[i][j] == 1)
                {
                    g->DrawRectangle(blackPen, 100, 100, j * 50, i * 50);
                    //Rectangle = x coordinate, y coordinate, width of rectangle, height of rectangle)
                }
                else if (test2[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    g->DrawRectangle(whitePen, i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
                }
            }
        }
```

It doesn't print the first row, can anyone guide me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time through each for loop j and i are 0, meaning the width and height of the rectangle will be 0 (i * 50 = 0 * 50 = 0)

Comment: Thanks! I am so muddle-headed :)